# Python - Capture multiple sub strings between multiple sub string Sizes a

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

The data that I have is in pretty bad format .txt . I am trying to capture meaning full words/sentences between these start and end strings. Right now, I have found about 4 types of sub strings patterns in a text. I am trying to capture the strings between these multiple start and end sub strings. I able to capture the first string occurrence, however not the 2nd, 3rd, ... etc correctly.

start and end strings:
FOO, BARS, BAR, BAR2

```
text = 'I do not want this FOO string1 BARS I do not want this FOO string 2 BAR I do not want this FOO string3 BAR2 I do not want this FOO string4 BARS '


snippet1 = text[text.index('FOO')+len('FOO'):text.index('BARS')] \
            if text[text.index('FOO')+len('FOO'):text.index('BARS')] else ''

snippet2 = text[text.index('FOO')+len('FOO'):text.index('BAR')] \
            if text[text.index('FOO')+len('FOO'):text.index('BAR')] else ''

snippet3 = text[text.index('FOO')+len('FOO'):text.index('BAR2')] \
            if text[text.index('FOO')+len('FOO'):text.index('BAR2')] else ''

# print(type(snippet1))
print('')
print('snippet1:',snippet1) #Output: snippet1:  string1
print('')
print('snippet2',snippet2) # Output: snippet2  string1
print('')
print('snippet3',snippet3) # Output: snippet3  string1 BARS I do not want this FOO string2 BAR I do not want this FOO string3

# How do I get this output? Is it possible to code this?
snippet1:  string1
snippet2:  string2
snippet3:  string3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is what you want.

```
def find_substrings(text, start_marker, end_marker):
    index = 0
    results = []

    while True:
        index = text.find(start_marker, index)
        if index == -1: # If the start string wasn't found then there are no more instances left in the string
            break
        index2 = text.find(end_marker, index+len(start_marker))
        if index2 == -1: # Sub string was not terminated. 
            break
        results.append(text[index+len(start_marker):index2])
        index = index2 + len(end_marker)

    return results
```

Currently you are using index (which is like find but will throw errors if it does not find anything) but it will start looking at the start of the string each time.

```
text = 'I do not want this FOO string1 BARS I do not want this FOO string 2 BAR I do not want this FOO string3 BAR2 I do not want this FOO string4 BARS '
find_substrings(text, "FOO ", " BAR")
```

will return

```
['string1', 'string 2', 'string3', 'string4']
```

Comment: Both the answers helped, but @TobySuch answer fit into to my code well. Thanks a bunch!!! I spent too long on fixing this!!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC: You can do this using [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
txt='I do not want this FOO string1 BARS I do not want this FOO string 2 BAR I do not want this FOO string3 BAR2 I do not want this FOO string4 BARS '
re.findall('FOO(.*?)BAR', txt)
```

will produce list of matching strings like this:

```
[' string1 ', ' string 2 ', ' string3 ', ' string4 ']
```

Update for matching with multiple keywords:

```
import re
txt='I do not want this FOO string1 BARS I do not want this FOO string 2 SECTION I do not want this FOO string3 BAR2 I do not want this FOO string4 BARS'
re.findall('FOO(.*?)[BAR|SECTION]', txt)
```

will result in:

```
[' string1 ', ' string 2 ', ' string3 ', ' string4 ']
```

Comment: You can cut off whitespaces: re.findall('FOO\s*(.*?)\s*BAR', text)